# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'chat' telebot

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Я добавил функцию вывода id в сообщение, но при выполнении этой функции бот выдает ошибку, пользуюсь библиотекой telebot.

```
import time
import telebot
import webbrowser

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['My steam', '/steam'])
def site():
webbrowser.open('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}', )


@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}')
elif message.text.lower() == 'id':
    bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, f'ID: {message.from_user.id}')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

[image: Такую ошибку выдает]

Comment: замените `bot.reply_to` на `bot.send_message`, вы же хотите, чтобы бот вам сообщил ваш `id`?

Comment: По поводу кода, вы не делаете табуляцию в теле функции из-за этого будет ошибка(возможно просто так вставилось)

Comment: что такое табуляция?))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Метод `reply_to` первым аргументом принимает просто `message`

```
@bot.message_handler()
def info(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'id':
        bot.reply_to(message, f'ID: {message.from_user.id}') # просто message
```

Документация: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.reply_to